# Ext.Net GridPanel filters not working

Tags: asp.net, html, ext.net

I have a ext:GridPanel.

What happens is the First Column's filter works fine, but it loads that same filter for all other columns as well, and they all filter the first column.

Can you please have a look at my GridPanel

```
    <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanelStudentHistory" runat="server" StoreID="StoreStudentHistory" StripeRows="true" Header="true" Title="Students" Border="true" AutoHeight="true" AutoWidth="true">
    <LoadMask ShowMask="false" />
    <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel2" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <ext:Column runat="server" ColumnID="StudentNo" Header="Student Number" Sortable="true" Width="150px" DataIndex="StudentNo" />
            <ext:Column runat="server" ColumnID="StudentName" Header="Student Name" Sortable="true" Width="250px" DataIndex="StudentName" />
            <ext:Column runat="server" ColumnID="StudentSurname" Header="Student Surname" Sortable="true" Width="250px" DataIndex="StudentSurname" />
            <ext:Column runat="server" ColumnID="AbsentDays" DataIndex="AbsentDays" Header="Absent Days" Width="50" Sortable="true"/>
            <ext:Column runat="server" ColumnID="marks" DataIndex="marks" Header="Marks" Align="Right" Width="150" Sortable="false"/>
        </Columns>
    </ColumnModel>
    <View>
        <ext:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DeferEmptyText="false" EmptyText="No Items Available At This Moment" />
    </View>
    <Plugins>
        <ext:GridFilters runat="server" ID="GridFilters3" Local="true">
            <Filters>
                <ext:NumericFilter DataIndex="StudentNo"  />
                <ext:StringFilter DataIndex="StudentName" />
                <ext:StringFilter DataIndex="StudentSurname" />
            </Filters>
        </ext:GridFilters>
    </Plugins>
    <BottomBar>
        <ext:PagingToolbar ID="PagingToolBar1" runat="server" StoreID="StoreStudentHistory" PageSize="50"
            HideRefresh="true" DisplayInfo="true" DisplayMsg="Displaying Students {0} - {1} of {2}" />
    </BottomBar>
</ext:GridPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand well what happens.

Could you start a new forum thread with a full sample to reproduce here?
http://forums.ext.net/forumdisplay.php?18-2-x-Help

Comment: I just got a notification that my answer has been accepted. For sure, I was going to make a comment, not an answer. Now I cannot delete it, because it is accepted answer:)